# Angular Service can set data from one controller but not the other

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, service, controller

I have a module and two controllers :

```
var module = angular.module("app", ["agGrid", "ngAnimate", "ngSanitize", "ngDialog"])


module.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "dataService","$timeout","dateFilter","ngDialog", "$http", function ($scope, $http, $timeout, dateFilter, ngDialog, dataService) {
}]);


module.controller("modalCtrl", ["$scope", "ngDialog", "dataService", function ($scope, ngDialog, dataService) {


$scope.printEntity = function () {
    console.log(dataService.getEntityArray());
}

}]);
```

And a service:

```
 module.factory("dataService", function () {

var entityArrayService = [];

return {
    setEntityArray: function (entityArray) {
        entityArrayService = entityArray;
    },
    getEntityArray: function () {
        return entityArrayService;
    }

};

});
```

I can call `dataService.setEntityArray(array)` from inside my SECOND controller, but when i try to call this from my first controller it tells me `dataService.setEntityArray is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of dependency injections is incorrect. Arguments in the controller function must repeat the order of the elements in the array. In your case `dataService` is the second argument:

```
module.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", "dataService","$timeout","dateFilter","ngDialog", "$http", function ($scope, dataService, $timeout, dateFilter, ngDialog, $http) {
}]);
```

Comment: You are kidding me, the order matters!?  Thanks!  will accept when time runs out.

Comment: Of course :) Thats the point of array notation so that Angular knows what argument corresponds to what service. So that after minification when it's `['dataService', '$http', function(a, b) {}]` Angular knows that `a` is `DataService`, etc.

Comment: Oh I see!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid order of the variables in the first controller definition. It should be:

```
function ($scope, dataService, $timeout, dateFilter, ngDialog, $http)
```